# Error Loading Shared Libraries when Installing Redhat Directory Server

Tags: rhel, libraries, dynamic-linking

While Installing the Red Hat Directory Server on the Red Hat Linux Server 5 (x86_64)i am getting the following error

bin/slapd/server/dsktune: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I thought may be this is the dependency problem and I have installed the rpm compat-libstdc++ from the redhat CD of x66_64 and i queried using

rpm -qa | grep compat-libst* i am able to find the rpm in the installed packages.

What could be the resolution for this issue ?

EDIT1: I have run the following command ldconfig -v | grep libstdc

> [root@redhot redhat-ds]# ldconfig -v | grep libstdc
>
> ```
>   libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.8
>   libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
>   libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.8
> ```

EDIT2:

```
[root@hadoopredhot server]# ldd -v dsktune 
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00489000)
        libstdc++.so.5 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x004f4000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00d85000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00347000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0032a000)

        Version information:
        ./dsktune:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libcrypt.so.1:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libm.so.6:
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libc.so.6:
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

EDIT3:

```
[root@hadoopredhot server]# ldconfig -v 

/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libvmGuestLib.so:
    libvmGuestLib.so -> libvmGuestLib.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libvmGuestLib.so:
    libvmGuestLib.so -> libvmGuestLib.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libvmGuestLibJava.so:
    libvmGuestLibJava.so -> libvmGuestLibJava.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libvmGuestLibJava.so:
    libvmGuestLibJava.so -> libvmGuestLibJava.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libDeployPkg.so:
    libDeployPkg.so -> libDeployPkg.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libDeployPkg.so:
    libDeployPkg.so -> libDeployPkg.so
/lib:
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.5.so
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.5.so
    libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.2
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.5.so
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.5.so
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.5.so
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.5.so
    libnss_ldap.so.2 -> libnss_ldap-2.5.so
    libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8b
    libaudit.so.0 -> libaudit.so.0.0.0
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.5.so
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.5.so
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 -> libgmodule-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-4.1.2-20070626.so.1
    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.81.0
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.5.so
    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.81.5
    libnss_db.so.2 -> libnss_db-2.2.so
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.5.so
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.5.so
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 -> libgthread-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libasound.so.2 -> libasound.so.2.0.0
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libexpat.so.0 -> libexpat.so.0.5.0
    libcrypto.so.6 -> libcrypto.so.0.9.8b
    libdevmapper-event.so.1.02 -> libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.5.so
    libcap.so.1 -> libcap.so.1.10
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.5.so
    libdevmapper.so.1.02 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02
    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.81.2
    libtermcap.so.2 -> libtermcap.so.2.0.8
    libauparse.so.0 -> libauparse.so.0.0.0
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.5.so
    libiw.so.28 -> libiw.so.28
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils-1.2.so
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.5.so
    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.5.so
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.2.0
    libvolume_id.so.0 -> libvolume_id.so.0.66.0
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libdb-4.3.so -> libdb-4.3.so
    ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.5.so
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.5.so
    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.0
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.5.so
/lib64:
    libnss_winbind.so.2 -> libnss_winbind.so.2
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libproc-3.2.7.so -> libproc-3.2.7.so
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.5.so
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.5.so
    libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.2
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.5.so
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.5.so
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.5.so
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.5.so
    libnss_ldap.so.2 -> libnss_ldap-2.5.so
    libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8b
    libaudit.so.0 -> libaudit.so.0.0.0
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.5.so
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.5.so
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libnss_wins.so.2 -> libnss_wins.so.2
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.5.so
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 -> libgmodule-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-4.1.2-20070626.so.1
    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.81.0
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.5.so
    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.81.5
    libnss_db.so.2 -> libnss_db-2.2.so
    libsemanage.so.1 -> libsemanage.so.1
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.5.so
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.5.so
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 -> libgthread-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libasound.so.2 -> libasound.so.2.0.0
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libexpat.so.0 -> libexpat.so.0.5.0
    libcrypto.so.6 -> libcrypto.so.0.9.8b
    libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
    libdevmapper-event.so.1.02 -> libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.5.so
    libcap.so.1 -> libcap.so.1.10
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.5.so
    libdevmapper.so.1.02 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02
    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.81.2
    libtermcap.so.2 -> libtermcap.so.2.0.8
    libauparse.so.0 -> libauparse.so.0.0.0
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.5.so
    libiw.so.28 -> libiw.so.28
    libdevmapper-event-lvm2mirror.so.2.02 -> libdevmapper-event-lvm2mirror.so.2.02
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils-1.2.so
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.5.so
    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.1200.3
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.5.so
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.2.0
    libvolume_id.so.0 -> libvolume_id.so.0.66.0
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libdb-4.3.so -> libdb-4.3.so
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.5.so
    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.0
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.5.so
/usr/lib:
    libnssckbi.so -> libnssckbi.so
    libgailutil.so.18 -> libgailutil.so.18.0.1
    libplc4.so -> libplc4.so
    libplds4.so -> libplds4.so
    libaudiofile.so.0 -> libaudiofile.so.0.0.2
    libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.5
    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.3.0
    libsmime3.so -> libsmime3.so
    libsoftokn3.so -> libsoftokn3.so
    libesddsp.so.0 -> libesddsp.so.0.2.36
    libgnutls-extra.so.13 -> libgnutls-extra.so.13.0.6
    libgnutls-openssl.so.13 -> libgnutls-openssl.so.13.0.6
    libgnome-keyring.so.0 -> libgnome-keyring.so.0.0.1
    libnspr4.so -> libnspr4.so
    libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0 -> libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
    libnss3.so -> libnss3.so
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
    libcupsimage.so.2 -> libcupsimage.so.2
    libdbus-glib-1.so.2 -> libdbus-glib-1.so.2.0.0
    libkadm5clnt.so.5 -> libkadm5clnt.so.5.1
    libORBit-imodule-2.so.0 -> libORBit-imodule-2.so.0.0.0
    libcryptsetup.so.0 -> libcryptsetup.so.0.0.0
    libegroupwise-1.2.so.12 -> libegroupwise-1.2.so.12.0.0
    libfontconfig.so.1 -> libfontconfig.so.1.1.0
    libmetacity-private.so.0 -> libmetacity-private.so.0.0.0
    libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
    libhistory.so.5 -> libhistory.so.5.1
    libpspell.so.15 -> libpspell.so.15.1.3
    libkdb5.so.4 -> libkdb5.so.4.0
    libebook-1.2.so.9 -> libebook-1.2.so.9.0.0
    libbdevid.so.5.1.19.6 -> libbdevid.so.5.1.19.6
    libgcrypt.so.11 -> libgcrypt.so.11.2.2
    libavahi-core.so.4 -> libavahi-core.so.4.0.5
    libcamel-1.2.so.0 -> libcamel-1.2.so.0.0.0
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 -> libgstbase-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libgamin-1.so.0 -> libgamin-1.so.0.1.7
    libXdmcp.so.6 -> libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.5
    libecal-1.2.so.7 -> libecal-1.2.so.7.0.0
    libcups.so.2 -> libcups.so.2
    libXft.so.2 -> libXft.so.2.1.2
    libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0 -> libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libspi.so.0 -> libspi.so.0.10.11
    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
    libatk-1.0.so.0 -> libatk-1.0.so.0.1212.0
    libeel-2.so.2 -> libeel-2.so.2.16.1
    libORBit-2.so.0 -> libORBit-2.so.0.1.0
    libXinerama.so.1 -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0
    libXau.so.6 -> libXau.so.6.0.0
    libXRes.so.1 -> libXRes.so.1.0.0
    libdrm.so.2 -> libdrm.so.2.0.0
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.5
    libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
    libgnomeui-2.so.0 -> libgnomeui-2.so.0.1600.0
    libkadm5srv.so.5 -> libkadm5srv.so.5.1
    libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.060501
    libgstdataprotocol-0.10.so.0 -> libgstdataprotocol-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libformw.so.5 -> libformw.so.5.5
    libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0
    libgnomecanvas-2.so.0 -> libgnomecanvas-2.so.0.1400.0
    libavahi-glib.so.1 -> libavahi-glib.so.1.0.1
    libgnomeprint-2-2.so.0 -> libgnomeprint-2-2.so.0.1.0
    libaspell.so.15 -> libaspell.so.15.1.3
    libkrb5.so.3 -> libkrb5.so.3.3
    libsvrcore.so.0 -> libsvrcore.so.0.0.0
    libpango-1.0.so.0 -> libpango-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libgnomeprintui-2-2.so.0 -> libgnomeprintui-2-2.so.0.1.0
    libSM.so.6 -> libSM.so.6.0.0
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 -> libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
    libbz2.so.1 -> libbz2.so.1.0.3
    libpanel-applet-2.so.0 -> libpanel-applet-2.so.0.2.11
    libgtkhtml-3.8.so.15 -> libgtkhtml-3.8.so.15.3.9
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libparted-1.8.so.0 -> libparted-1.8.so.0.0.1
    libgnome-2.so.0 -> libgnome-2.so.0.1600.0
    libgstnet-0.10.so.0 -> libgstnet-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libXss.so.1 -> libXss.so.1.0.0
    libgnutls.so.13 -> libgnutls.so.13.0.6
    libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.8
    libgnome-menu.so.2 -> libgnome-menu.so.2.1.3
    libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2
    libcrack.so.2 -> libcrack.so.2.8.0
    libpanelw.so.5 -> libpanelw.so.5.5
    libgnome-desktop-2.so.2 -> libgnome-desktop-2.so.2.2.21
    libxkbfile.so.1 -> libxkbfile.so.1.0.2
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libutempter.so.0 -> libutempter.so.1.1.4
    libavahi-common.so.3 -> libavahi-common.so.3.4.3
    libXxf86vm.so.1 -> libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
    libXdamage.so.1 -> libXdamage.so.1.0.0
    libXxf86misc.so.1 -> libXxf86misc.so.1.1.0
    libxklavier.so.11 -> libxklavier.so.11.0.0
    libglade-2.0.so.0 -> libglade-2.0.so.0.0.7
    libusbpp-0.1.so.4 -> libusbpp-0.1.so.4.4.4
    libk5crypto.so.3 -> libk5crypto.so.3.1
    libhal.so.1 -> libhal.so.1.0.0
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 -> libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libcairo.so.2 -> libcairo.so.2.9.2
    libfreebl3.so -> libfreebl3.so
    libavahi-client.so.3 -> libavahi-client.so.3.2.1
    libreadline.so.5 -> libreadline.so.5.1
    libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
    libtiffxx.so.3 -> libtiffxx.so.3.8.2
    libldap-2.3.so.0 -> libldap-2.3.so.0.2.15
    libwnck-1.so.18 -> libwnck-1.so.18.2.3
    libbonoboui-2.so.0 -> libbonoboui-2.so.0.0.0
    libtiff.so.3 -> libtiff.so.3.8.2
    libfam.so.0 -> libfam.so.0.0.0
    libckyapplet.so.1 -> libckyapplet.so.1.0.0
    libkrb4.so.2 -> libkrb4.so.2.0
    libgdict-1.0.so.5 -> libgdict-1.0.so.5.0.5
    libgnome-mag.so.2 -> libgnome-mag.so.2.1.1
    libglut.so.3 -> libglut.so.3.8.0
    libXi.so.6 -> libXi.so.6.0.0
    libnuma.so.1 -> libnuma.so.1
    libsasl2.so.2 -> libsasl2.so.2.0.22
    libedataserverui-1.2.so.8 -> libedataserverui-1.2.so.8.0.0
    libgnomevfs-2.so.0 -> libgnomevfs-2.so.0.1600.2
    liblber-2.3.so.0 -> liblber-2.3.so.0.2.15
    libhal-storage.so.1 -> libhal-storage.so.1.0.0
    libgconf-2.so.4 -> libgconf-2.so.4.1.0
    libdb_cxx-4.3.so -> libdb_cxx-4.3.so
    libnautilus-extension.so.1 -> libnautilus-extension.so.1.1.0
    libbonobo-activation.so.4 -> libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0
    libcspi.so.0 -> libcspi.so.0.10.11
    libnautilus-burn.so.4 -> libnautilus-burn.so.4.0.0
    libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
    libXrandr.so.2 -> libXrandr.so.2.0.0
    libdes425.so.3 -> libdes425.so.3.0
    libIDL-2.so.0 -> libIDL-2.so.0.0.0
    libedata-cal-1.2.so.6 -> libedata-cal-1.2.so.6.0.0
    libpangox-1.0.so.0 -> libpangox-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libbonobo-2.so.0 -> libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0
    libkrb5support.so.0 -> libkrb5support.so.0.1
    libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.5
    libXcursor.so.1 -> libXcursor.so.1.0.2
    libXrender.so.1 -> libXrender.so.1.3.0
    libedataserver-1.2.so.7 -> libedataserver-1.2.so.7.1.0
    libstartup-notification-1.so.0 -> libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
    libloginhelper.so.0 -> libloginhelper.so.0.0.0
    libssl3.so -> libssl3.so
    libICE.so.6 -> libICE.so.6.3.0
    libgssrpc.so.4 -> libgssrpc.so.4.0
    libcamel-provider-1.2.so.8 -> libcamel-provider-1.2.so.8.1.0
    libexchange-storage-1.2.so.2 -> libexchange-storage-1.2.so.2.0.0
    libgnome-window-settings.so.1 -> libgnome-window-settings.so.1.0.0
    libedata-book-1.2.so.2 -> libedata-book-1.2.so.2.3.0
    libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.5
    libldap_r-2.3.so.0 -> libldap_r-2.3.so.0.2.15
    libpng.so.3 -> libpng.so.3.10.0
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 -> libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libXt.so.6 -> libXt.so.6.0.0
    libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.6.26
    libaio.so.1.0.0 -> libaio.so.1.0.0
    libXevie.so.1 -> libXevie.so.1.0.0
    libsoup-2.2.so.8 -> libsoup-2.2.so.8.5.0
    libesd.so.0 -> libesd.so.0.2.36
    libart_lgpl_2.so.2 -> libart_lgpl_2.so.2.3.17
    libaio.so.1 -> libaio.so.1.0.1
    libgtop-2.0.so.7 -> libgtop-2.0.so.7.0.0
    libmenuw.so.5 -> libmenuw.so.5.5
    libdaemon.so.0 -> libdaemon.so.0.2.4
    libgpm.so.1 -> libgpm.so.1.19.0
    libX11.so.6 -> libX11.so.6.2.0
    libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.10.0
    libXfixes.so.3 -> libXfixes.so.3.1.0
    libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.3.10
    libgnomecups-1.0.so.1 -> libgnomecups-1.0.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64:
    liblwres.so.9 -> liblwres.so.9.1.3
    libnssckbi.so -> libnssckbi.so
    libgailutil.so.18 -> libgailutil.so.18.0.1
    libgsf-1.so.114 -> libgsf-1.so.114.0.1
    libplc4.so -> libplc4.so
    libplds4.so -> libplds4.so
    libaudiofile.so.0 -> libaudiofile.so.0.0.2
    libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.5
    librpmbuild-4.4.so -> librpmbuild-4.4.so
    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.3.0
    libsmime3.so -> libsmime3.so
    libsoftokn3.so -> libsoftokn3.so
    libssldap60.so -> libssldap60.so
    libgettextsrc-0.14.6.so -> libgettextsrc-0.14.6.so
    libstunnel.so -> libstunnel.so
    libesddsp.so.0 -> libesddsp.so.0.2.36
    libdmraid.so.1.0.0.rc13 -> libdmraid.so.1.0.0.rc13
    libmagic.so.1 -> libmagic.so.1.0.0
    libpoppler.so.1 -> libpoppler.so.1.0.0
    libisccfg.so.1 -> libisccfg.so.1.0.6
    libgnutls-extra.so.13 -> libgnutls-extra.so.13.0.6
    libgnutls-openssl.so.13 -> libgnutls-openssl.so.13.0.6
    libprldap60.so -> libprldap60.so
    libbluetooth.so.2 -> libbluetooth.so.2.4.1
    libgnome-keyring.so.0 -> libgnome-keyring.so.0.0.1
    libnspr4.so -> libnspr4.so
    libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0 -> libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
    libnss3.so -> libnss3.so
    librpmio-4.4.so -> librpmio-4.4.so
    libcdda_interface.so.0 -> libcdda_interface.so.0.9.8
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
    libcddb-slave2.so.0 -> libcddb-slave2.so.0.0.0
    libcupsimage.so.2 -> libcupsimage.so.2
    libgucharmap.so.5 -> libgucharmap.so.5.0.1
    libOggFLAC++.so.2 -> libOggFLAC++.so.2.0.0
    libhesiod.so.0 -> libhesiod.so.0.0.0
    libdbus-glib-1.so.2 -> libdbus-glib-1.so.2.0.0
    libsefs.so.3 -> libsefs.so.3
    libdmx.so.1 -> libdmx.so.1.0.0
    libpcrecpp.so.0 -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
    libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
    libsysfs.so.2 -> libsysfs.so.2.0.0
    libkadm5clnt.so.5 -> libkadm5clnt.so.5.1
    libORBit-imodule-2.so.0 -> libORBit-imodule-2.so.0.0.0
    libcryptsetup.so.0 -> libcryptsetup.so.0.0.0
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 -> libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libegroupwise-1.2.so.12 -> libegroupwise-1.2.so.12.0.0
    libfontconfig.so.1 -> libfontconfig.so.1.1.0
    libmetacity-private.so.0 -> libmetacity-private.so.0.0.0
    libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
    libhistory.so.5 -> libhistory.so.5.1
    libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.125.so
    libgsf-gnome-1.so.114 -> libgsf-gnome-1.so.114.0.1
    libpspell.so.15 -> libpspell.so.15.1.3
    libkdb5.so.4 -> libkdb5.so.4.0
    libebook-1.2.so.9 -> libebook-1.2.so.9.0.0
    libgs.so.8 -> libgs.so.8.15
    libXfontcache.so.1 -> libXfontcache.so.1.0.0
    libbdevid.so.5.1.19.6 -> libbdevid.so.5.1.19.6
    libtheora.so.0 -> libtheora.so.0.2.0
    libgcrypt.so.11 -> libgcrypt.so.11.2.2
    libavahi-core.so.4 -> libavahi-core.so.4.0.5
    libcamel-1.2.so.0 -> libcamel-1.2.so.0.0.0
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 -> libgstbase-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libgamin-1.so.0 -> libgamin-1.so.0.1.7
    libXdmcp.so.6 -> libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
    libFLAC.so.7 -> libFLAC.so.7.0.0
    libuser.so.1 -> libuser.so.1.1.6
    libspeex.so.1 -> libspeex.so.1.3.0
    libnm-util.so.0 -> libnm-util.so.0.0.0
    libgweather.so.0 -> libgweather.so.0.0.0
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.5
    libecal-1.2.so.7 -> libecal-1.2.so.7.0.0
    libcups.so.2 -> libcups.so.2
    libfontenc.so.1 -> libfontenc.so.1.0.0
    libXft.so.2 -> libXft.so.2.1.2
    liblvm2cmd.so.2.02 -> liblvm2cmd.so.2.02
    libFS.so.6 -> libFS.so.6.0.0
    libgstcdda-0.10.so.0 -> libgstcdda-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0 -> libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libspi.so.0 -> libspi.so.0.10.11
    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
    libatk-1.0.so.0 -> libatk-1.0.so.0.1212.0
    libXaw.so.6 -> libXaw6.so.6.0.1
    libldap60.so -> libldap60.so
    librom1394.so.0 -> librom1394.so.0.3.0
    libeel-2.so.2 -> libeel-2.so.2.16.1
    libORBit-2.so.0 -> libORBit-2.so.0.1.0
    libXinerama.so.1 -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0
    libgdbm.so.2 -> libgdbm.so.2.0.0
    libijs-0.35.so -> libijs.so
    libpcreposix.so.0 -> libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
    libXau.so.6 -> libXau.so.6.0.0
    libXRes.so.1 -> libXRes.so.1.0.0
    libvte.so.9 -> libvte.so.9.1.5
    libraw1394.so.8 -> libraw1394.so.8.1.1
    libdrm.so.2 -> libdrm.so.2.0.0
    libexslt.so.0 -> libexslt.so.0.8.13
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libqpol.so.1 -> libqpol.so.1
    libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.5
    libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
    libgnomeui-2.so.0 -> libgnomeui-2.so.0.1600.0
    liblockdev.so.1 -> liblockdev.so.1.0.1
    libkadm5srv.so.5 -> libkadm5srv.so.5.1
    libXaw.so.7 -> libXaw7.so.7.0.0
    libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.060501
    libgstdataprotocol-0.10.so.0 -> libgstdataprotocol-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libopcodes-2.17.50.0.6-5.el5.so -> libopcodes-2.17.50.0.6-5.el5.so
    libgtksourceview-1.0.so.0 -> libgtksourceview-1.0.so.0.0.0
    libformw.so.5 -> libformw.so.5.5
    libOpenIPMIposix.so.0 -> libOpenIPMIposix.so.0.0.1
    libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0
    libgphoto2.so.2 -> libgphoto2.so.2.1.1
    libdv.so.4 -> libdv.so.4.0.2
    libgnomecanvas-2.so.0 -> libgnomecanvas-2.so.0.1400.0
    libavahi-glib.so.1 -> libavahi-glib.so.1.0.1
    libgnomeprint-2-2.so.0 -> libgnomeprint-2-2.so.0.1.0
    libnetsnmp.so.10 -> libnetsnmp.so.10.0.1
    libaspell.so.15 -> libaspell.so.15.1.3
    libldif60.so -> libldif60.so
    librpmdb-4.4.so -> librpmdb-4.4.so
    libkrb5.so.3 -> libkrb5.so.3.3
    libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
    libsvrcore.so.0 -> libsvrcore.so.0.0.0
    librsvg-2.so.2 -> librsvg-2.so.2.16.1
    libpango-1.0.so.0 -> libpango-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libgnomeprintui-2-2.so.0 -> libgnomeprintui-2-2.so.0.1.0
    libSM.so.6 -> libSM.so.6.0.0
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 -> libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
    libOpenIPMIutils.so.0 -> libOpenIPMIutils.so.0.0.1
    libbz2.so.1 -> libbz2.so.1.0.3
    libOpenIPMIpthread.so.0 -> libOpenIPMIpthread.so.0.0.1
    libpanel-applet-2.so.0 -> libpanel-applet-2.so.0.2.11
    libbfd-2.17.50.0.6-5.el5.so -> libbfd-2.17.50.0.6-5.el5.so
    liblftp-jobs.so.0 -> liblftp-jobs.so.0.0.0
    libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.0.6
    libgtkhtml-3.8.so.15 -> libgtkhtml-3.8.so.15.3.9
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libostyle.so.0 -> libostyle.so.0.0.1
    libparted-1.8.so.0 -> libparted-1.8.so.0.0.1
    libgnome-2.so.0 -> libgnome-2.so.0.1600.0
    libscrollkeeper.so.0 -> libscrollkeeper.so.0.0.0
    libI810XvMC.so.1 -> libI810XvMC.so.1.0.0
    libnetsnmptrapd.so.10 -> libnetsnmptrapd.so.10.0.1
    librpcsecgss.so.2 -> librpcsecgss.so.2.0.1
    libgstnet-0.10.so.0 -> libgstnet-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libXfont.so.1 -> libXfont.so.1.4.1
    librpm-4.4.so -> librpm-4.4.so
    libXss.so.1 -> libXss.so.1.0.0
    libgnutls.so.13 -> libgnutls.so.13.0.6
    libOpenIPMI.so.0 -> libOpenIPMI.so.0.0.5
    libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.8
    libisc.so.11 -> libisc.so.11.1.1
    libFLAC++.so.5 -> libFLAC++.so.5.0.0
    libgstaudio-0.10.so.0 -> libgstaudio-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libgnome-menu.so.2 -> libgnome-menu.so.2.1.3
    libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2
    libvorbisfile.so.3 -> libvorbisfile.so.3.1.1
    libcrack.so.2 -> libcrack.so.2.8.0
    libbeecrypt.so.6 -> libbeecrypt.so.6.4.0
    libpanelw.so.5 -> libpanelw.so.5.5
    libnotify.so.1 -> libnotify.so.1.1.0
    libdns.so.22 -> libdns.so.22.0.1
    libbind9.so.0 -> libbind9.so.0.0.8
    libgnome-desktop-2.so.2 -> libgnome-desktop-2.so.2.2.21
    libxkbfile.so.1 -> libxkbfile.so.1.0.2
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.1000.4
    libutempter.so.0 -> libutempter.so.1.1.4
    libpython2.4.so.1.0 -> libpython2.4.so.1.0
    libavahi-common.so.3 -> libavahi-common.so.3.4.3
    libXxf86vm.so.1 -> libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
    libXv.so.1 -> libXv.so.1.0.0
    libXdamage.so.1 -> libXdamage.so.1.0.0
    libOpenIPMIui.so.1 -> libOpenIPMIui.so.1.0.1
    libXxf86misc.so.1 -> libXxf86misc.so.1.1.0
    libxklavier.so.11 -> libxklavier.so.11.0.0
    libglade-2.0.so.0 -> libglade-2.0.so.0.0.7
    libxslt.so.1 -> libxslt.so.1.1.17
    libusbpp-0.1.so.4 -> libusbpp-0.1.so.4.4.4
    libk5crypto.so.3 -> libk5crypto.so.3.1
    libtcl8.4.so -> libtcl8.4.so
    libhal.so.1 -> libhal.so.1.0.0
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 -> libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libpoldiff.so.1 -> libpoldiff.so.1
    libcairo.so.2 -> libcairo.so.2.9.2
    liblftp-tasks.so.0 -> liblftp-tasks.so.0.0.0
    libogg.so.0 -> libogg.so.0.5.3
    libgssapi.so.2 -> libgssapi.so.2.0.0
    libXmuu.so.1 -> libXmuu.so.1.0.0
    libfreebl3.so -> libfreebl3.so
    libsnmp.so.10 -> libsnmp.so.10.0.1
    libavahi-client.so.3 -> libavahi-client.so.3.2.1
    libreadline.so.5 -> libreadline.so.5.1
    libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
    libtiffxx.so.3 -> libtiffxx.so.3.8.2
    libldap-2.3.so.0 -> libldap-2.3.so.0.2.15
    libXxf86dga.so.1 -> libXxf86dga.so.1.0.0
    libwnck-1.so.18 -> libwnck-1.so.18.2.3
    libbonoboui-2.so.0 -> libbonoboui-2.so.0.0.0
    libospgrove.so.0 -> libospgrove.so.0.0.1
    libtiff.so.3 -> libtiff.so.3.8.2
    libbrlapi.so.0.4 -> libbrlapi.so.0.4.1
    libviaXvMCPro.so.1 -> libviaXvMCPro.so.1.0.0
    libfam.so.0 -> libfam.so.0.0.0
    libgnomespeech.so.7 -> libgnomespeech.so.7.0.1
    libckyapplet.so.1 -> libckyapplet.so.1.0.0
    libwacomcfg.so.0 -> libwacomcfg.so.0.0.1
    libIPMIlanserv.so.0 -> libIPMIlanserv.so.0.0.1
    libkrb4.so.2 -> libkrb4.so.2.0
    libgdict-1.0.so.5 -> libgdict-1.0.so.5.0.5
    libgsttag-0.10.so.0 -> libgsttag-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libOggFLAC.so.3 -> libOggFLAC.so.3.0.0
    libidn.so.11 -> libidn.so.11.5.19
    libgnome-mag.so.2 -> libgnome-mag.so.2.1.1
    libnewt.so.0.52 -> libnewt.so.0.52.1
    libglut.so.3 -> libglut.so.3.8.0
    libXi.so.6 -> libXi.so.6.0.0
    libnuma.so.1 -> libnuma.so.1
    libsasl2.so.2 -> libsasl2.so.2.0.22
    libsmbclient.so.0 -> libsmbclient.so
    libedataserverui-1.2.so.8 -> libedataserverui-1.2.so.8.0.0
    libgnomevfs-2.so.0 -> libgnomevfs-2.so.0.1600.2
    libogrove.so.0 -> libogrove.so.0.0.1
    liblber-2.3.so.0 -> liblber-2.3.so.0.2.15
    libhal-storage.so.1 -> libhal-storage.so.1.0.0
    libgstnetbuffer-0.10.so.0 -> libgstnetbuffer-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libgnome-media-profiles.so.0 -> libgnome-media-profiles.so.0.0.0
    libgconf-2.so.4 -> libgconf-2.so.4.1.0
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 -> libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libvorbisenc.so.2 -> libvorbisenc.so.2.0.2
    libdb_cxx-4.3.so -> libdb_cxx-4.3.so
    libnautilus-extension.so.1 -> libnautilus-extension.so.1.1.0
    libhugetlbfs.so -> libhugetlbfs.so
    libiec61883.so.0 -> libiec61883.so.0.0.0
    libnm_glib.so.0 -> libnm_glib.so.0.0.0
    libbonobo-activation.so.4 -> libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0
    libcspi.so.0 -> libcspi.so.0.10.11
    libevent-1.1a.so.1 -> libevent-1.1a.so.1.0.2
    libnautilus-burn.so.4 -> libnautilus-burn.so.4.0.0
    libbind.so.4 -> libbind.so.4.0.5
    libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
    libavc1394.so.0 -> libavc1394.so.0.3.0
    libXrandr.so.2 -> libXrandr.so.2.0.0
    libcdda_paranoia.so.0 -> libcdda_paranoia.so.0.9.8
    libpoppler-glib.so.1 -> libpoppler-glib.so.1.0.0
    libisccc.so.0 -> libisccc.so.0.2.2
    libdes425.so.3 -> libdes425.so.3.0
    libIDL-2.so.0 -> libIDL-2.so.0.0.0
    libedata-cal-1.2.so.6 -> libedata-cal-1.2.so.6.0.0
    libpangox-1.0.so.0 -> libpangox-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libcroco-0.6.so.3 -> libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
    libbonobo-2.so.0 -> libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0
    libpcap.so.0.9.4 -> libpcap.so.0.9.4
    libkrb5support.so.0 -> libkrb5support.so.0.1
    libapol.so.3 -> libapol.so.3
    libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.1400.9
    libgphoto2_port.so.0 -> libgphoto2_port.so.0.6.1
    libnetsnmpagent.so.10 -> libnetsnmpagent.so.10.0.1
    libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.3.0.0
    libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.5
    libXcursor.so.1 -> libXcursor.so.1.0.2
    libXrender.so.1 -> libXrender.so.1.3.0
    libgettextlib-0.14.6.so -> libgettextlib-0.14.6.so
    libedataserver-1.2.so.7 -> libedataserver-1.2.so.7.1.0
    libstartup-notification-1.so.0 -> libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
    libloginhelper.so.0 -> libloginhelper.so.0.0.0
    libssl3.so -> libssl3.so
    libICE.so.6 -> libICE.so.6.3.0
    libgssrpc.so.4 -> libgssrpc.so.4.0
    libcamel-provider-1.2.so.8 -> libcamel-provider-1.2.so.8.1.0
    libexchange-storage-1.2.so.2 -> libexchange-storage-1.2.so.2.0.0
    libXmu.so.6 -> libXmu.so.6.2.0
    libgnome-window-settings.so.1 -> libgnome-window-settings.so.1.0.0
    libnetsnmpmibs.so.10 -> libnetsnmpmibs.so.10.0.1
    libedata-book-1.2.so.2 -> libedata-book-1.2.so.2.3.0
    libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.5
    libOpenIPMIcmdlang.so.0 -> libOpenIPMIcmdlang.so.0.0.5
    libldap_r-2.3.so.0 -> libldap_r-2.3.so.0.2.15
    libnfsidmap.so.0 -> libnfsidmap.so.0.2.0
    libviaXvMC.so.1 -> libviaXvMC.so.1.0.0
    libpng.so.3 -> libpng.so.3.10.0
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 -> libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.8.1
    libvorbis.so.0 -> libvorbis.so.0.3.1
    libosp.so.5 -> libosp.so.5.0.0
    libXt.so.6 -> libXt.so.6.0.0
    libpcsclite.so.1 -> libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
    libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.6.26
    libaio.so.1.0.0 -> libaio.so.1.0.0
    libXevie.so.1 -> libXevie.so.1.0.0
    libsoup-2.2.so.8 -> libsoup-2.2.so.8.5.0
    libexif.so.12 -> libexif.so.12.0.1
    libesd.so.0 -> libesd.so.0.2.36
    libgstriff-0.10.so.0 -> libgstriff-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libart_lgpl_2.so.2 -> libart_lgpl_2.so.2.3.17
    libaio.so.1 -> libaio.so.1.0.1
    libgstrtp-0.10.so.0 -> libgstrtp-0.10.so.0.6.0
    libgtop-2.0.so.7 -> libgtop-2.0.so.7.0.0
    libmenuw.so.5 -> libmenuw.so.5.5
    libOpenIPMIglib.so.0 -> libOpenIPMIglib.so.0.0.1
    libdaemon.so.0 -> libdaemon.so.0.2.4
    liboil-0.3.so.0 -> liboil-0.3.so.0.1.0
    libgpm.so.1 -> libgpm.so.1.19.0
    libX11.so.6 -> libX11.so.6.2.0
    libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.10.0
    libXfixes.so.3 -> libXfixes.so.3.1.0
    libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.3.10
    libXTrap.so.6 -> libXTrap.so.6.4.0
    libnl.so.1 -> libnl.so.1.0-pre5
    libnetsnmphelpers.so.10 -> libnetsnmphelpers.so.10.0.1
    libgnomecups-1.0.so.1 -> libgnomecups-1.0.so.1.0.0
/lib/i686: (hwcap: 0x0008000000000000)
/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib64/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/usr/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
```

> [root@hadoopredhot server]# cat /etc/redhat-release
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)

Where i can download this shared library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `dsktune` a 32-bit or 64-bit executable? Whichever it is, you need a matching `libstdc++.so.5`. You seem to have two libraries for version 6 but only one for version 5; presumably you have version 6 for both architectures but version 5 only for the other architecture. Install `compat-libstdc++` for the architecture that `dsktune` is for.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
ldconfig -v | grep libstdc
```

will you see a libstdc++.so.5? Or did you run `ldconfig` after installing of compat-libstdc++ package?

Comment: What will say `ldd dsktune`? Maybe it can be about architecture, what said @Gilles.

Comment: updated the question with the command

Comment: Please, can you post whole `ldconfig -v` log?

Comment: Updated the Question .....

Comment: Thanks. Please, use utility `file` to check, on which architectude you have dsktune, in this way: `file /whole/path/to/dsktune`. Your compat-libstdc++ package is 64-bit (it is in the /usr/lib64 directory), but you can use utility `file` to check this library too. And architecture of dsktune and architecture of library must be same.